# Observable.Using( ) cancellation

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a observable made by the `Using` helper:

```
var o = Observable.Using(
 () => { 
          return new MyResource 
       },
 res => {
          return new Observable.Create<string>(observer => ....);
        });
```

How can I cancel the observable? And by that make sure `MyResource` is disposed of?

I see there are a `Observable.Using( )` that includes a `cancellationToken`, but signature is so different, that I'm not able to make it work...

**Update:** 
As James points out, by disposing the observable, my resource will be disposed as well. In my case, a plain disposal is not enough. I need to call a method on the resource first. How can that be archived?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your Update.

Comment: "disposing the subscription to the observable", not "disposing the observable".  Understanding the difference will help you better understand Rx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to clean up an observable - just the subscription. Simply call `Dispose` on the handle returned from `Subscribe` when you make a subscription to cancel it.

The resource created by the *factory* delegate supplied as the first argument to `Using` has a lifetime governed by lifetime of subscriptions to the observable created by `Using`.

Here's an example:

```
var xs = Observable.Using(
    () => {                        
        var resource =  Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Binned"));
        Console.WriteLine("Created");
        return resource;
    },
    res => Observable.Never<Unit>());

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing");
var sub1 = xs.Subscribe();
var sub2 = xs.Subscribe();
Console.WriteLine("Disposing");            
sub1.Dispose();
```

Gives output:

```
Subscribing
Created
Created
Disposing
Binned
```

Since `sub2` never finishes and isn't disposed, there is only a single `Binned` message displayed.

In this example, `sub1` completes immediately and there is no cancellation:

```
var xs = Observable.Using(
    () => {                        
        var resource =  Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Binned"));
        Console.WriteLine("Created");
        return resource;
    },
    res => Observable.Return(1));

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing");
var sub1 = xs.Subscribe();
```

This time the resource is still cleaned up, because the subscription terminated normally:

```
Subscribing
Created
Binned
```

The purpose of the overload of `Using` sporting cancellation tokens is to allow you to cancel asynchronous creation of the resource and the dependent observable. The cancellation tokens are signalled on disposal of subscription handles - of course this scenario is only really going to be useful if you have relatively lengthy creation times and early disposal is likely.

### Addendum

To address the corollary to your question:

> ...a plain disposal is not enough. I need to call a method on the resource first. How can that be [achieved]?

From your resource factory method (the first argument to using), do this:

```
var xs = Observable.Using(
    () =>
    {                        
        var processHandle = /* code to create process */
        return Disposable.Create(() => /* code to kill process using processHandle */;
    },
    // Rest of code...
```

`Disposable.Create` is a helper method you can use that accepts in `Action` that's invoked upon disposal.

Comment: ok. In my case, though, the resource is a running process, and I wan't to kill that process, so some how, some where, I need to add a call to `resource.Kill()`, or the process will continue run long after my application has evaporated.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for trying to help me out here. I have to admit I have a hard time understanding these things. So....
Today I return a `Process` from the first parameter, which give me access to this process in the second parameter, where I can hook the std out of the process and turn that into a observable of string. By returning `Disposable.Create(() => ...)` - how can I still access the process in the second parameter?

Comment: Sorry Vegar, I probably made the point badly - thinking that you just needed your process running rather than having access to it in the second factory. You probably want to create a class that encapsulates creating your process and provides access to it. Have it implement `IDisposable` and have its `Dispose` method do your clean up. Return a created instance of this class in the first factory (which thus creates the process). This instance will be passed as the argument of the second factory function, and its `Dispose` will ultimately be called by `Using` at the right time.

Comment: No, I'm the one hiding details, believing them irrelevant. Encapsulating the process in a new disposable is what I just tried out. And It looks like it works pretty ok. 
I have another option as well. The running process will exit if gets signaled through StdIn (key-press), but I have problem with that approach as well. Watch out for yet another observable question :-)

Comment: I ended up with the graceful shutdown through giving the process input.
The help you gave me still deserve a green check mark, though :-)